# Alinhamento de imagens com inputs

Tags: javascript, css

Estou tentando alinhar o input abaixo de cada imagem depois de ter efetuado uploads utilizando file reader.
Segue print da tela e os códigos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;

            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {

                    $($.parseHTML('<img class="img-galeria  img-thumbnail img-galeria" >')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                    $($.parseHTML('<input class="form-control painel-input-galeria" type="text" name="titulo-img" placeholder="título da imagem">')).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);

                },
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            }
        }
    };
    $('#imagem').on('change', function() {
        imagesPreview(this, 'div.galeria');
    });

});
```

HTML

CSS já tentei várias alternativas e não consegui.

Comment: HMTL   <div class="galeria"></div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <input id="imagem" type="file"  multiple />

Answer (score 0):

Cria um elemento à volta desses dois e depois dentro desse elemento usa 
 `display: block;` ou `width: 100%;` no `input` e `img`.

```js
var imagens = [
  'https://madeby.google.com/static/images/google_g_logo.svg',
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/c8/Yahoo_Y.svg/300px-Yahoo_Y.svg.png'
];

var placeToInsertImagePreview = $('.galeria');

imagens.forEach(function(img) {
  var contentor = $('<div class="contentor"/>').appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
  contentor.html('<img class="img-galeria  img-thumbnail img-galeria" src="' + img + '">');
  contentor.append('<input class="form-control painel-input-galeria" type="text" name="titulo-img" placeholder="título da imagem">');
});
```

```css
.contentor {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.contentor>* {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="galeria"></div>
```